# Why does delete[] throw an exception here?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I'm trying to implement the merge sort algorithm, and I can't figure out why `delete[] right` throws an exception :

`Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap`.

Removing the line fixes the issue, but this creates a memory leak, right? `delete[] left` here does not cause a problem.

```
void Merge(int data[], int from, int middle, int to)
{
    int leftLength = middle - from + 1;
    int rightLength = to - middle;
    
    int* left = new int[leftLength + 1];
    int* right = new int[rightLength + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < leftLength; i++)
    {
        left[i] = data[from + i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rightLength; i++)
    {
        right[i] = data[middle + i + 1];
    }

    left[leftLength] = INT_MAX;
    right[rightLength] = INT_MAX;
    
    int leftPointer = 0;
    int rightPointer = 0;

    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
    {
        if (left[leftPointer] < right[rightPointer])
        {
            data[i] = left[leftPointer];
            leftPointer++;
        }
        else
        {
            data[i] = right[rightPointer];
            right++;
        }
    }

    delete[] left;
    delete[] right;
}
```

Comment: Is it really a true exception? That would be astonishing.

Comment: By the way, if you use `Merge()` as part of mergesort, consider allocating just one buffer at the start of mergesort, and passing it along for reuse as needed.

Comment: If you had used `std::vector` instead of messing around with manual memory management, this would have been a compilation error.

Answer (score 6):

The pointer `right` is changed by the line

```
right++;
```

After executing the line, `right` is no longer a pointer allocated via `new[]` and therefore passing that to `delete[]` is illegal.

The line should be changed to

```
rightPointer++;
```

just like you are incrementing `leftPointer` instead of `left` in the previous line.

Comment: Thank you very much! I assumed it would be something silly like that!